# Expanding a tooltip after a few seconds

Tags: wpf

I want to make a tooltip that will expand itself after a few seconds of users focus.

Don't know how to exactly describe this, but got a perfect example.
This is a tooltip that is used in AutoCAD Architecture 2014. When I move the mouse over any button, a typical tooltip appears. But after 2-3 seconds of holding the mouse here, the tooltip expands itself into a bigger one. Here are before and after screenshots:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

And some of my test code here.
Two buttons, one with a standard tooltip that I want to be at the beginning and the second with its expanded content. How to convert it into one?

```
 <StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Advanced" Height="50" Width="150" TextBlock.FontSize="20">
        <Button.ToolTip>
            <TextBlock Text="Test"/>
        </Button.ToolTip>
    </Button>
    <Button Height="50" Width="150" Content="Advanced 2" TextBlock.FontSize="20">
        <Button.ToolTip>
            <StackPanel Height="200" Width="200">
                <StackPanel Height="30" Width="200" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                <Image VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Height="30" Source="C:\tmp\ask.png" Name="image1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Here will be some more text."/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button.ToolTip>
    </Button>

</StackPanel>
```

And the last one, how to make an 'expanding' transition while transforming the tooltip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a custom style that displays the control with a delay.

```
    <Window.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="DelayShowImage">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel}}" Value="true">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="VisibleStory">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                   Duration="0"
                                   BeginTime="0:0:02">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="VisibleStory"/>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

 <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Advanced" Height="50" Width="150" TextBlock.FontSize="20">
            <Button.ToolTip>
                <TextBlock Text="Test"/>
            </Button.ToolTip>
        </Button>
        <Button Height="50" Width="150" Content="Advanced 2" TextBlock.FontSize="20">

            <Button.ToolTip>
                <StackPanel Height="200" Width="200">
                    <StackPanel Height="30" Width="200" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    <Image VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Height="30" Source="C:\tmp\ask.png"  Name="image1"
                           Style="{StaticResource DelayShowImage}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Here will be some more text."/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button.ToolTip>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

The code from above, displays the Tooltip in the second button, and after 2000ms(0:0:02), it displays the image. You can change the style to be used by a different control that you want to display later.

Comment: Ok, but how to make a transition between them? To make it more fluent, less 'pop-up'?

Comment: That's one case where you do need to use animations, i.e. transition the size of a control and blend from one panel to another. That's not really related to popups per-se though, and it's still something you can (and should IMO) control via data-binding.

Answer (score 4):

Start by declaring a couple of DataTemplates for your tooltips:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="SmallToolTip">
        <TextBlock Text="Hello World!" FontSize="12" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="LargeToolTip">
        <TextBlock Text="Hello World!" FontSize="50" />
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
```

Now set the tooltip on your control to be a ContentPresenter, and add a handler for the `Loaded` event:

```
<Rectangle Width="1000" Height="800" Fill="Blue">
    <Rectangle.ToolTip>
        <ContentPresenter Name="theToolTip" Loaded="ToolTip_Loaded" />
    </Rectangle.ToolTip>
</Rectangle>
```

Back in your code-behind you need to create a `DispatcherTimer` which you'll activate when the `Loaded` function is invoked; this function will also set the template to the small one. When the timer fires you simply stop it and set the larger template:

```
private DispatcherTimer Timer;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // set up the timer
    this.Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    this.Timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
    this.Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
}

private void ToolTip_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    theToolTip.ContentTemplate = this.Resources["SmallToolTip"] as DataTemplate;
    this.Timer.Start();
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Timer.Stop();
    theToolTip.ContentTemplate = this.Resources["LargeToolTip"] as DataTemplate;
}
```

I'm using plain-vanilla WPF here, but it's also easy to do in MVVM. In that case you simply bind the `Loaded` event to a command in your viewmodel (EventToCommand or whatever) and have both that handler and the timer handler toggle a boolean property indicating whether the tooltip should be large or small. Then back in your view you simply use a DataTrigger to set the appropriate template. (In practice it's a little bit more tricky, because tooltips aren't actually part of the "regular" visual tree and thus don't inherit the parent control's DataContent, but you can usually work around that by using a [BindingProxy](https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/)).

Comment: Although this approach is valid and works - the solution provided by @Lupu Silviu is cleaner.

Comment: You are right @Mark, both work. It depends on what the user wants and his particularities in the request.

Comment: I'll be honest....XAML is incredibly powerful, but that doesn't mean it's always the best tool for the job. I personally believe it's good practice to try keep as much logic out of the view as possible, but I'll concede that that's largely because I'm an MVVM purist. I do think though that in cases like this it's very helpful to put breakpoints or even logging output etc in the code and possibly even unit test the behaviour; that's virtually impossible to do when you're trying to do everything in XAML.